# How to align a control and keep it's size relative to the sizeable form?

Tags: c#, controls, alignment

I have a `ListView` control in my form.  When the form resizes, I want this `ListView` to resize at the same time with the form, so it keeps the 12px right margin.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If it is WinForms, then use Anchors, if it is WPF, then use DockPanel, for example and set margins for ListView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use anchoring on the control. If you anchor it to the right and left, it will grow and shrink with the resize:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use the Anchor property to set an anchor at the relevant directions, so your control will be 
resize together with its container